# C++ Store Keys with String in tree? Rollup

Tags: c++, tree

I need to store Numbers of Models which are mapped to Models. For example:

```
    1:99:54:42 -> Black Tea -> /models/liquid/tea/blacktea.model
    1:99:54:43 -> Green Tea
    1:99:53:1  -> normal Coffee
```

I cannot change the numbers.
If there is no model for Green Tea, I just want to look for a model with any tea like: 1:99:54:*.

My Solution is to store the all the mapped Models which exist, so I would not store Green Tea if there is no equivalent Model, into a structure like a tree. So I could easily just look at all the children if the given number doesnt exist.

//edit
Yes there are very many keys without Models. I only want to load keys with Models in some kind of Tree, Map or List. I need to search for a Model until I take the Default 0:0:0:0.
It should be some kind of Rollup from 1:xc:ys:zz to 1:*:*:*

Comment: "Is this efficient?" - at the moment it's not even clear how you want to do it, so it's impossible to tell. please clarify.

Comment: It depends on too many factors, try to profile your solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the entries in a `std::map` keyed on number - including those without a model - then you can search for the key using `lower_bound` and iterate up and down to find the closest key with a model... should be fairly efficient unless you have a particularly long run of model-less keys, in which case you may want to keep a second `set` with just the keys with models - `lower_bound` can get you a nearby  key and you can compare the two keys around your actual key to see which is better numerically.  There are further indexing/optimisation opportunities, but it depends a bit on whether you populate the data once then search it repeatedly, or keep doing insertions and deletions intermingled with searches.

For example:

```
struct Tea { string name_; string model_; };
std::map<string, Tea> number_to_tea;
std::set<string> numbers_with_models;

// when inserting...
if (!tea.model_.empty())
    numbers_with_models.insert(number);
number_to_tea[number] = tea;

// when searching...
if (numbers_with_models.empty())
     return/break/whatever...
auto i = numbers_with_models.lower_bound(number);
if (i != numbers_with_models.end())
    if (i.first == number) // perfect match...
        // ...
    else if (i == numbers_with_models.begin())
        // closet element is first element... do whatever...
    else
    {
        if (i.first - number < number - std::prev(i).first)
            // following element is closer...
        else
            // previous element is closer...
    }
else
    // last element is closest...
```

Comment: Black Tea and Green Tea are not adjacent keys. There could potentially be lots of keys in between, when you comparing in lexical order

Comment: @Enigma: I said above "keyed on time", not the type of tea.  The question says "store Number of Models" (which I think is the "1:99:54:42" bit - on closer inspection not a time so I'll correct that in my answer) "...mapped to Models".

Comment: Ok but I dont want Tea to be a own struct. Because Tea would just be the 1:99:"54":*. And if I have no Model for Tea and none for anything else from that Group, I take 1:99:*:* and if there is none I take 1:*:*:*. Maybe nested maps would work?

Comment: @BjörnT: if you want to map from a "number" like 1:99:54:42 to potentially both the string "Black Tea" and the model name, then you have to combine their storage somehow... you could concatenate them into a single string with a separator character, or put them in a `std::pair<>` (which is just a templates `struct`) or create your own.  If you want to drop the trailing part of the number and search again, you can use a `map` and `set` as in my answer but will need to knock the last few characters off each time you search the `set`, i.e. to get "1:99:54:" then "1:99:", then "1:".